# Why isn't my attempt to load a value defined in an environment variable definition file as a multiline string in VS Code with Python working?

Tags: json, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I noticed that I can't load data with the JSON module from an environment variable that is presented as a multiline string in VS Code. However, I can load it successfully from the command line. I don't understand why this is happening.

my code loads JSON data from the environment:

```py
from environs import Env
from os import getenv
from typing import Dict

env: Env = Env()
env_file: Optional[str] = getenv("ENV_FILE")
if not env_file:
    print("You need to start this script with ENV_FILE variable!")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    env.read_env(path=env_file)

_server_data = env.str("SERVER_DATA")
SERVER_DATA: Dict = json.loads(_server_data)
if not SERVER_DATA:
    raise ValueError("empty SERVER_DATA")
for item in SERVER_DATA:
    print(f'{item} : {SERVER_DATA[item]}')
```

my .env file:

```
SERVER_DATA = '{"test_server": "server",
                "test_server2": "server2"}'
```

If I run this code from the command line, it works as expected:

```
ENV_FILE=.env python main.py                                                                                                                                                  
test_server : server
test_server2 : server2
```

But if I run this from VS Code, I get an exception:

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/user/proj/test_vscode/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    SERVER_DATA: Dict = json.loads(_server_data)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Okay, I can change the environment variable to be used in a single line, but this can be a bit frustrating.

Comment: your code says `SERVER_DATA: Dict` and the error says `SERVER_DATA: List`, the culprit is the content of `_server_data`, but you don't print that, or use a debugger to inspect, add a lot more print statements to detect where the problem is

Comment: what command does VSC use to run the program, what is the use of `else`

Comment: print the current directory **inside** the script

Comment: Regarding the SERVER_DATA: Dict type annotation, it was a mistake, but I fixed it after sending it here. So, that is not the problem.

About printing inside the script, I can load JSON data successfully if the data is in a single line. However, the problem arises when the JSON data spans multiple lines

Comment: Regarding the what going on, this code only for show the problem, of course this isn't real code.
VS Code runs main.py without any arguments, but in the settings, I have specified an "env" parameter where I provide the path to the .env file.

Comment: if this code does not have the problem why show it to us, if we can't replicate what is the point of the question, if the multi line `SERVER_DATA` works from the command line why not in VSC

Comment: Yes, I have a question about why, if I set the SERVER_DATA value as a multilinestring in the .env file, it doesn't work in VS Code. However, if I run the code from the command line like this: ENV_FILE=.env python main.py, it works fine.

If I change the SERVER_DATA line in the .env file to a single line, it starts working in VS Code. It's not a major issue, but I would like to understand why this happens and if there's any way to avoid this problem without converting the JSON data into a long single line.

Comment: ok, i found why this happen (why i don't look at vscode git?, sorry for spending time). if someone runs into the same problem, it won't work then that's it:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9251

Comment: why does `environs` behave different inside VSC, what does `vscode-python` modify in this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variable definition files do not support multiline values. [It says so in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file):

> Multiline values aren't supported, but references to previously defined environment variables are allowed.

There's also a related issue ticket where this was discussed: [Support multiline environment variables in .env files #9251](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9251), where [the maintainers commented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9251#issuecomment-579998047):

> We think there isn't an enough widespread need for this to warrant the maintenance cost for the feature.

As for your JSON parser error, I think that might be a result of the multiline value not being supported.